# How to specify the location of SQlite database android?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I create an SQlite Database I dont find it in resources of my  android project so  I want to locolize it in my hard disk , and how to proceed to open it ?

Comment: You say hard disk. Do you mean you are writing this for a computer? Or do you mean phone's local memory? Cause the database is already created on the phone's local memory.

Comment: there is any file .db on the hard disk ?

Answer (score 1):

You `can't` directly save your database into `harddisk` But you can create database in sdcard

then copy that database from sdcard to your harddisk.

Then you can access that database using [SQLite Database browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Comment: so your .db file want to access that file in your android app from ur hard disk ?

Comment: Actually I want to view all records in my .db file , like a file of mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some selection from your database to see all records 
[here](http://www.tutomobile.fr/comment-utiliser-sqlite-sous-android-tutoriel-android-n%C2%B019/19/10/2010/) is a tutorial that can help you